# High Latencies In Socket.IO

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm developing a game using Socket.IO . I'm finding that the latencies are very high ie 250 milliseconds even when running on localhost. Is this normal ?

Here is the code I'm using to calculate the latency :

```
function startLatencyPoller(socket,callback)
  {
      setInterval(function() {
      var startTime = Date.now();
      socket.emit('ping');
      socket.on('pong', function() {
        latency = (Date.now() - startTime) /2; //round trip time / 2
        callback(latency);
  });
}, 2000);

}
```

My question is whether its normal for Socket.IO to have latencies as high as 250 ms even on a local network and whether there are ways to  reduce it further.

EDIT:
I checked the transport and right now I'm using websocket as the transport.

EDIT:
Problem has been fixed after editing code as per below answer (remove listener avoid them piling up) :

```
setInterval(function() {

     var startTime = 0;
     var socketFunction = function() {
        latency = (Date.now() - startTime) /2; //round trip time / 2
        callback(latency);
        socket.removeListener('pong',socketFunction);
    };

    socket.on('pong', socketFunction);
    startTime = Date.now(); 
    socket.emit('ping');


}, 5000);
```

Comment: No, it's not normal. It's hard to tell where the cause might be. What's the latency if you use a normal ping in the terminal?

Comment: Local pings are very fast less than 1 ms. I'm not sure how to diagnose this.

Comment: Im running into 250 ms even when i m using localhost on the same machine. This is consistent even across different machines I've tried it in. Even if you hit it from another machine on the same network it still doesnt go lower than 250 ms on average.

Comment: On further inspection its pretty weird. I get 0.5 100 .. 2000 .. 5000 .. 0.5 .. 1 .. its pretty sporadic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with this function. If you setinterval a socket.on it means you are adding many listeners to the same event and that will be increasing the execution at each iteration. So first thing, remove that socket.on to outside the setinterval. Isn't your code blocking somewhere also? Assuming your cpu is not bogged with other stuff running, it can be some other event delaying it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer !! You da real MVP :D. I updated my question showing how to fix it using your advice.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you wait a second or so before measuring ping as the initial connection socket can clog up system resources, resulting in a longer ping time. Might want to add a timer to your ping check.
2. Localhost/development environment should have some overhead ping as it is probably not a dedicated webserver.